# Finding key of weak crypto

Tags: encryption, cryptography

i'm a novice and trying the security shepard project where you have to pass challenges. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Security_Shepherd
I did all of the challenges but one that i have a really a hard time with.

To complete this challenge you have to find the key to an encryption method.
They just give you an application that can decrypt encrypted text.

`IAAAAEkQBhEVBwpDHAFJGhYHSBYEGgocAw==` gives `This crypto is not strong`.

Unlike other challenges there is no information in the source code.

I don't understand how I'm supposed to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Give it a shot first and show us some code and what has and hasn't worked first... The aim here is to get help and guidance, not to get someone else to do all the work for you

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I didn't try a lot because i'm really lost and don't know how to proceed. I tried to convert it from b64 but it gives garbage. I searched a lot on how to find which encryption method is used but did not find anything. Just a little clue would help me

Comment: Some ideas: The lesson which ends in that particular challenge should give some hints about what kinds of encryption may have been used. If you do some research on how the cyphertext looks like on each of those, you may be able to narrow down (or even pinpoint to) the encryption being used. If you end up with a hash algorithm rather than an encryption algorithm, you may try to find known collisions for it. If it's an actual encryption algorithm, knowing the cyphertext AND the plaintext may help bruteforcing it to find the key that was used

Comment: having said all that, there's a lot of information that's probably already there in the lesson. This is a lot like actual hacking: you'll need to do some research :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find the algo, just try to find the algos which are most unlikely to be possible. for a instant, this is not a classic mono-alphabetic or key-less transposition cipher. On the other hand compare input and output bit sizes. Narrow down your possibilities like that and it will helps you to decide which cryptanalysis method to be used.

This may be not the perfect approach, but sure it's a start.